# How to restrict options in HTML form based on database contents?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I'm looking for a way to dynamically restrict the options in a search form, based on the actual database contents. I'm aiming to both speed up searching and avoiding empty results...

I have no idea what terminology to use to describe this (so I may be searching badly), and I don't have many concrete examples, but here is one: the
[Rendition Project database search](https://www.therenditionproject.org.uk/prisoners/search.html). There are four "dropdown" form fields, with over 20 options under the first, over 30 options under the second and so on.

The behaviour that interests me in the given example is the following: If you set the first field to the first option [Afghanistan], immediately the second field's options are reduced to two [Afghanistan/COBALT and Afghanistan/all]; and vice versa if you have a clean form sheet and set the second field to Afghanistan/BROWN then there's only 2 options under the first field [Turkey and Pakistan].

This is clearly an elegant way to reduce searches to manageable sizes. To a large extent, webshops like Amazon also display this behaviour by whittling down product categories and then allowing ticking boxes by brand or quality-rating ("three or more stars" etc), or pack-size and other ad-hoc categories, but (a) this is much more advanced than I need and (b) this is far from the instant feedback of the example, requiring reload (as expected for querying a db with millions of items; or probably querying a temporary table with the thousands of initial results).

I have a database with a similar number of product items [a few hundred] and search criteria [five]; as in the given example some field values are much more "sensitive" (as in, different values drastically increase/reduce database results), where some combinations of five search criteria give a few dozens of results BUT there's also combinations of three search criteria that already give empty results. [E.g. for a hardware store, clearly a "0--25$" price search will contain many dozens of results for screws-and-nails, but zero for chainsaws.]

So I don't want my visitors to have to find the "sensitive" values by trial and error! In the given sample you can see the sensitivity before your eyes, and hence set/release the four values as needed.

It's for a website written in WordPress, which so far isn't using any external plugins [a load-data-from-CSV plugin was used to read the data in, and a self-written plugin defines a Custom Post Type and its taxonomies and so forth; presentation by self-written theme], just default form fields and so forth. Default database and so forth.

Comment: Try freelancer.com

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is a complicated procedure. The generic answer that you have to work with, is AJAX. Such data manipulation as you describe, is not possible in the HTML level (especially the sensitive information, that if it's handled at that point, it means it's been already exposed, and the attacker just needs to press an F12 - on windows).

In simple terms:

1. On keypress, make ajax search request for available fields with the
   given string.
2. Backend retrieves and provides all the possible results that start with the given string.
3. Present the available values upon AJAX success.

And just to make it clear, this is not an HTML issue. HTML is just responsible for formatting what you want to present at this point.